# Rails: How to render a nested partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path

I am trying to make an app with Rails 4 and Simple Form.

I have a projects model, a project_questions model and a project answer model.

The associations are:

Project.rb:

```
   has_many :project_questions, dependent: :destroy#, through: :projects
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_questions
```

Project_question.rb:

```
belongs_to :project#, counter_cache: true
  has_one :project_answer, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_answer
```

Project answer.rb:

```
  belongs_to :project_questions#, counter_cache: true
  belongs_to :user
```

My routes are nested:

```
  resources :projects do
    resources :project_questions do
      resources :project_answers
    end
  end
```

My project show, includes a partial to show questions asked about the project.

```
  <%= render 'project_questions/pqps' %>
```

Inside that project-question partial(pqps), I am trying to render the project answers partial so that the answer sits beneath the question.

```
  <% @project.project_questions.each do |singleQuestion| %>

      <div class="categorytitle">
        <%= singleQuestion.title %>

      </div>
      <div class="generaltext">
        <%= singleQuestion.try(:content) %>
      </div>
      <span class="editproject">
        <% if current_user.id == @project.creator_id %>

            <%= link_to 'Answer this question', new_project_project_question_project_answer_path(:project_id => @project.id, :project_question_id => singleQuestion.id) %>
<% else %>
            <%= render 'project_answers/answers' %>

<% end %>
```

I'm struggling, because the code I have in the project_answer partial view is:

```
        <%= @project.project_questions.project_answers.answer %>
```

When I try this, I get this error:

```
undefined method `project_answers' for #`<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_ProjectQuestion:0x000001039ebcc8>`
```

I have tried all forms and combinations of pluralising different bits of that project answer line of code, but nothing works.

When I try the answer as: 
            <%= @project.project_questions.project_answer.answer %>

```
undefined method `project_answer' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_ProjectQuestion:0x00000102b59318>
```

I don't understand why that is.

In my project answer controller, I have:

```
class ProjectAnswersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_project
  before_action :set_project_question
  before_action :set_project_answer, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  # GET /project_answers
  # GET /project_answers.json
  def index
    @project_answers = ProjectAnswer.all
  end

  # GET /project_answers/1
  # GET /project_answers/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /project_answers/new


  def new
    @project_answer = @project_question.build_project_answer
  end

  # GET /project_answers/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /project_answers
  # POST /project_answers.json
  def create
    @project_answer = @project_question.build_project_answer(project_answer_params)


    respond_to do |format|
      if @project_answer.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project answer was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @project_answer }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @project_answer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /project_answers/1
  # PATCH/PUT /project_answers/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project_answer.update(project_answer_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @project_answer, notice: 'Project answer was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @project_answer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /project_answers/1
  # DELETE /project_answers/1.json
  def destroy
    @project_answer.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to project_answers_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.

    def set_project
      @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    end

    def set_project_question
      @project_question = @project.project_questions.find(params[:project_question_id])
    end


  def set_project_answer
      @project_answer = ProjectAnswer.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def project_answer_params
      params[:project_answer].permit(:answer, :project_question_id, :id)
    end
end
```

I had thought that was supposed to let me just use @project.answer.answer, but I have also tried that and it doesnt work either.

Can anyone see what i need to do to render the answer to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you properly read your error

```
undefined method project_answers' for
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_ProjectQuestion:0x000001039ebcc8>
```

It clearyly states that ***you are calling project_answers on a collection and not a single record. Also you have 1-1 association on ProjectQuestion and ProjectAnswer models so it should be project_answer and not project_answers***

Fix:

Depending on the HTML inside your partial you can use any one of them:

```
<%= render partial: 'project_answers/answers', locals: {some_local_variable_used_in_partial: singleQuestion.project_answer}  %>
```

For details check out [`using partials`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)

Edit:

You are still calling project_answer on a collection. You need to iterate over project_questions and then render answers for it. Inside your partial you need to have:

```
<% @project.project_questions.each do |question| %>
  <%= question.project_answer.answer %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you Mandeep. I appreciate you're trying to help.  Each question only has 1 answer. I don't understand how there can be a collection for that association. Thanks anyway.

Comment: When I try your second suggestion (having tried each of answer and answers) I get this error: undefined method `question_answer' for #<ProjectQuestion:0x0000010fcd24a8>

Comment: @user2860931 my bad, you were using project_answers method so thought it was 1-N relationship. Updated my answer.

Comment: That also doesn't work I'm afraid. I've tried both:                 <%= render partial: 'project_answers/answers', locals: {@project_answer_id => singleQuestion.project_answer}  %>
 and                 <%= render partial: 'project_answers/answers', locals: {@project_answer_id: singleQuestion.project_answer}  %>
and get this error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end
Although I'm not clear whether you mean to give it the attribute name that I want it to render (which is :answer) or the :id for the attribute itself.

Comment: @user2860931 what error do you get? can you post logs from terminal and also the project_answers/answers partial

Comment: The answers partial is in the question above and has:             <%= @project.project_questions.project_answer.answer %>

Comment: @user2860931 btw please read the link I have posted in my answer. Unless you read it, you won't understand what is going on

Comment: I don't understand the final paragraph. I tried your suggested line (which does not involve a collection) and got the error I set out above.  When I try to adapt your suggestion under the final paragraph of your response, by updating my project_answer partial to refer to singleQuestion instead of project_question, I get an error which says: 
syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end
...tput_buffer = @output_buffer; =  = local_assigns[:];;@output...

Comment: When i try adding:                <%= singleQuestion.project_answer.answer %>
to my project_quesiton partial, I get: undefined method `answer' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Hi Mandeep, I have read the rails guide several times over. I've come to this forum because I don't understand how to use what its suggesting.

Comment: @user2860931 Ok! What is it that you didn't understand? project.project_questions is not a single record, it's a collection of records because each project has many project questions and you are calling project_answer method on that collection of records, not a single record. You are getting last error because you don't have project_answer for one of your questions

Comment: No, that can't be right. I got that error when I answered a question, it submitted and get that error

Comment: @user2860931 your error clearly says you are calling answer method on a nil class :) Anyways you can use  <%=singleQuestion.project_answer.try(:answer) %> . It won't raise an error even if answer is nil for some project_answer

Comment: I don't actually know what that error message means. That's part of the difficulty in learning this, the syntax is only clear once you've learned what everyone assumes you already know. Thank you for your help

Comment: @user2860931 no issues, with practice you'll get them